# e.TotalBytesToReceive returns -1

Tags: c#, download, ftp, webclient

I have a ListBox that contains a list of DirectAdmin user backups. List is populated using `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory` and it looks like this:

[image]

I can download an archive using the button at the bottom right. When I click on the button, another form appears and downloads the archive.

[image]

My download code is this:

```
public static void DownloadFile(string server, string username, ...)
{
    Uri URI = new Uri($"ftp://{server}/{targetFilePath}");
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        if (progress != null)
        {
            client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(progress);
        }
        if (complete != null)
        {
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(complete);
        }
        before?.Invoke();
        client.DownloadFileAsync(URI, localFilePath);
    }
}
```

and this is what I pass to the `DownloadFile()` method for the `DownloadProgressChanged` event:

```
delegate (object s2, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e2)
{
    TransferLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
       TransferLabel.Text = $"{(e2.BytesReceived / 1024).ToString()} KB / {(e2.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024).ToString()} KB";
    });
    TransferProgressBar.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
    {
       TransferProgressBar.Value = (int)(e2.BytesReceived / (float)e2.TotalBytesToReceive * 100);
    });
}
```

I'm using this same approach to upload a file and it works fine, but with download `e2.TotalBytesToReceive` returns `-1` throughout the process:

[image]

and only when it's done, I get the correct value:

[image]

Why is that?

---

I've found a workaround to solve the problem. I'll change the ListBox to ListView and also store the filesize of the archives using `ListDirectoryDetails`. This way I can compare the `e.BytesReceived` to stored total bytes instead of `e.TotalBytesToReceive`. This would solve my problem, but I'm still curious about the problem. Why do I get `-1`? Am I doing something wrong, or is this a server related problem? Also is there anything I can do to fix it (get the correct value)?

Comment: Read Remarks > Note section here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadprogresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

With FTP protocol, `WebClient` in general does not know total download size. So you commonly get `-1` with FTP.

See also [Download file from FTP with Progress - TotalBytesToReceive is always -1?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4591059/850848#45660669)

Note that the behavior actually contradicts the .NET documentation, which says for [`FtpWebResponse.ContentLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebresponse.contentlength) (where the value of `TotalBytesToReceive` comes from):

> For requests that use the `DownloadFile` method, the property is greater than zero if the downloaded file contained data and is zero if it was empty.

But you will easily find out many of questions about this (like the one I've linked above), effectively showing that the behavior is not always as documented. The `FtpWebResponse.ContentLength` has a meaningful value for `GetFileSize` method only.

The `FtpWebRequest`/`WebClient` makes no explicit attempt to find out a size of the file that it is downloading. All it does is that it tries to look for `(xxx bytes).` string in `125`/`150` responses to `RETR` command. No FTP RFC mandates that the server should include such information. ProFTPD (see [`data_pasv_open` in `src/data.c`](https://github.com/proftpd/proftpd/blob/v1.3.6/src/data.c#L159)) and vsftpd (see `handle_retr` in `postlogin.c`) seem to include this information. Other common FTP servers (IIS, FileZilla) do not do this.

Comment: "So you always get -1 with FTP" - that's not true. I just checked on some public ftp server and it returns ContentLength just fine when using `DownloadFile`.

Comment: I've deleted it already, but it was completely regular. Basically just `new WebClient().DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("ftp://speedtest.tele2.net/500MB.zip"), output)` (with `DownloadProgressChanged` like in OP question).

Comment: @Evk OK, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly for HTTP downloads it's possible for the server not to supply size information when performing a file download and you're left with no sensible information until the server signals that it's done.

Not sure for FTP (I'd note that there's a separate `SIZE` command defined in the FTP command set and so including such information during a Retrieve may be considered redundant).

I'm slightly surprised that the documentation for `TotalBytesToRetrieve` isn't more explicit on the possibility that the information will not be available and what will  be returned in such circumstances.